# python: computing statistics on subset of an image

Tags: python, performance, loops, numpy, vectorization

I have an RGB image which is represented as a numpy array of size (500, 500, 3). I also have an array of size (500, 500) where each pixel has an integer value between 0 and 99 inclusive. This basically divides the image into many sub-region. Pixels belonging to a sub-array share the same integer index.

I am interested in doing some computations like computing the mean and standard deviation for each of these subsets. I can do this by looping over the image as follows (to compute the mean for example):

```
# image is of size (500, 500, 3) ->RGB values
# label is of size (500, 500) -> contains integers        
import numpy as np

mean = np.zeros((100, 3))
for i in range(0, 100):
    count = 0
    for x in range(0,500):
        for y in range(0,500):
            if label[x, y] == i:
                mean[i, :] += image[x, y,:]
                count = count + 1

    # Compute the mean
    if count > 0:
        mean[i,:] /= count
```

The way I am doing it includes lots of loops and it seems to be to be quite non-pythonic and I was wondering if there was a better (in sense of speed) way to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use logical indexing and masks:

```
image[label==i,:].mean(0)
```

Comment: Thanks! I feel embarrassed now writing that code segment. Can you explain what the parameter (0) to the mean function does? It seems to be computing mean along each axes (which is what I want!) but it is not clear to me from the documentation.

Comment: You get a two dimensional array, because the first two dimensions got flattened out by the mask, and the mean value is calculated over the first dimension, so you get a vector with 3 elements.

Answer (score 1):

you can make it a lot more 'pythonic', but as far as looping goes you can lose the first loop by retrieving the actual current intenger value from `label` by using the coordinates: `i=label[x:y]` instead of looping over all possible values.